# Ошибка в логах PHP

Tags: php

Заметил в логах PHP такую ошибку:

> PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference in

Вот собственно код:

```
'ext' => end(explode('.', $down[0]['url'])),
```

Направьте меня на истинный путь. Или это из-за версии php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат работы explode() сохраните в переменную:

```
$exp = explode('.', $down[0]['url']);
```

И потом эту переменную подставляйте в end():

```
end($exp)
```

> **Всё вместе будет выглядеть так:**

```
$exp = explode('.', $down[0]['url']);

$arr = array( 'ext' => end($exp) );
```

Comment: Данный код у меня как-бы в массиве
    $arr = array(
        'ext' => end(explode('.', $down[0]['url']))
    ); что именно нужно сделать, могли бы подробно описать, пожалуйста? Просто я не совсем гуру в php :)

Comment: @Webmaster подправил ответ.

Comment: Эдуард, спасибо большое, вроде ошибка исчезла.) Скажите, пожалуйста, а что было неправильно в моем коде? Что было не так?

Comment: @Webmaster проблема была в том, что функция [end()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.end.php) принимает параметр по ссылке `&`. А ссылаться можно только на значения, сохранённые в переменных, а не на значения, которые получены в результате вычисления какой либо функцией.

Comment: Благодарю Вас.)

Comment: Эдуард, у меня почему-то в логах ругается (возможно стало после) еще: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in именно на этот код $exp = explode('.', $down[0]['url']); не подскажете как это исправить?

Comment: @Webmaster ну, по отрывку кода сложно точно сказать. Попробуйте добавить проверку на существование: [смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/247d43fcaf9b39f8b2d95cd5c65abe82287659dd)